# Read a randomly generated number?

Tags: bash, archlinux

Im trying to use the `read` command to read a randomly generated number and then reuse it. Im using,

`read "$RANDOM" randomnumber`

```
echo "$randomnumber"
```

When I run it I get,

```
read: 'numbers': not a valid identifier
```

and the echo spits out $randomnumber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for `read` is `read [arguments] [var1 var2 ...]`.

Your `read $RANDOM randomnumber` is going to try to read input and split it into two variables (the result of `$RANDOM` and `randomnumber`). This will fail because numbers aren't valid shell variable names.

If you want to assign a "random" number to the `randomnumber` variable just use:

```
randomnumber=$RANDOM
echo "$randomnumber"
```

Answer (score -1):

This should be what you are looking for.

```
# !/bin/bash
read randomnumber
echo $randomnumber
```